# Using SCCM need to remove a folder under current logged user profile, hence a powershell to look at "C:\users" to get users and cycle through them

Tags: arrays, powershell, environment-variables

This is the script I have:

```
$TeamsPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($env:LOCALAPPDATA, 'Microsoft', 'Teams')
$TeamsUpdateExePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($env:LOCALAPPDATA, 'Microsoft', 'Teams', 'Update.exe')

try
{
    if (Test-Path -Path $TeamsUpdateExePath) {
        Write-Host "Uninstalling Teams process"

        # Uninstall app
        $proc = Start-Process -FilePath $TeamsUpdateExePath -ArgumentList "-uninstall -s" -PassThru
        $proc.WaitForExit()
    }
    if (Test-Path -Path $TeamsPath) {
        Write-Host "Deleting Teams directory"
        Remove-Item –Path $TeamsPath -Recurse
    }
}
catch
{
    Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_
    exit /b 1
}
```

It works fine if ran as current user. Problem is SCCM runs it as SYSTEM account therefore no folder gets removed.

Is there a way to look at folders name in "C:\users\" and based on names set the variable path to Start-Process accordingly? OR anything that could get me the name of the current user logged works fine too. I need to get rid of $env:LOCALAPPDATA and add something else I can't come up with.

Comment: SCCM gives you the ability to run as current user.  Can you just select that option?  What version of SCCM are you running.  What type of deployment is this?  Application, Package, Configuration Item?

Comment: Hi Paul, you are right and indeed with SCCM you can install as user but the latest msi from Microsoft requires admin rights. Now the problem is the msi install itself under program files and for every user who logs in, it copies itself under user profile %localappdata%. If you remove from SCCM its msi, you just remove the one under program files but the program under user profile it remains. You can script another deployment to remove the one under user profile using user rights but it fails on detection because you cannot detect files under user variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$users = Get-ChildItem C:\Users
foreach($user in $users){
    $TeamsPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($user.FullName, 'AppData', 'Local', 'Microsoft', 'Teams')
    $TeamsUpdateExePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($user.FullName, 'AppData', 'Local', 'Microsoft', 'Teams', 'Update.exe')

    $teamsPathCorrect = Test-Path $TeamsPath
    $TeamsUpdatePathCorrect = Test-Path $TeamsUpdateExePath

    if($TeamsUpdatePathCorrect){
        try{
            Write-Host "Uninstalling Teams process"

            # Uninstall app
            $proc = Start-Process -FilePath $TeamsUpdateExePath -ArgumentList "-uninstall -s" -PassThru
            $proc.WaitForExit()
        }catch{
            Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_
            exit /b 1
        }
    }
    if($TeamsPathCorrect){
        try{
            Write-Host "Deleting Teams directory"
            Remove-Item –Path $TeamsPath -Recurse
        }catch{
            Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_
            exit /b 1
        }
    }
}
```

This might help you out. This will check all folders/users in C:\Users and foreach found look for existing Microsoft Teams and update and remove accordingly.

Comment: this is it, thank you Bernard this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Perfect thanks for letting us know. If the question is solved, don't forget to mark the answer ;)